# Multiple methods named 'frame' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios

in xcode Version 9.4.1 [This is a third-party library](https://github.com/Roylee-ML/SwipeTableView), and I ran my project reporting an error, but it also ran in the sample project of the library, so there was no error reporting. I don't know why, thank you

```
-(CGFloat)lastItemMaxYForColumn:(NSInteger)columnIdx inSection:(NSInteger)sectionIdx {

    NSArray * itemsInColumn = self.columnRectsInSection[@(sectionIdx)][columnIdx];
    if (itemsInColumn.count == 0) {
        if([self.headerFooterItemAttributes[UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader] count] > sectionIdx) {

            CGRect headerFrame = [self.headerFooterItemAttributes[UICollecti//here is error --Multiple methods named 'frame' found onElementKindSectionHeader][sectionIdx] frame];with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

        return headerFrame.size.height;

            return headerFrame.size.height;
        }
        return 0.0f;
    } else {
        CGRect lastItemRect = [[itemsInColumn lastObject] CGRectValue];
        return CGRectGetMaxY(lastItemRect);
    }
}
```

[image: This is a description of the error message]

Comment: Add a cast to the proper type before calling `frame`, I assume you’re getting just an `id` and the system doesn’t know which `frame` method you want.

Comment: I also think so, but this is a third-party library, I can't contact the author quickly, can you give me a suggestion?